# Await of MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync never ends

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, async-await, task

With the await of MapLocationFinder my program still runs, even after trying to close it with Application.Current.Shutdown();. I'm a beginer.

I already tried to use CancellationToken or run this as Task. But I don't know if I had done this in the right way. I tried different thinks for some hours but nothing worked for me.

```
private async Task GetLocation()
    {
        var accesStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
        switch (accesStatus)
        {
            case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:
                // locate user
                var locator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
                var location = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
                var position = location.Coordinate.Point.Position;

                // get city name
                Geopoint geopoint = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition
                {
                    Latitude = position.Latitude,
                    Longitude = position.Longitude
                });
```

**Here the problem starts**

```
                MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(geopoint, MapLocationDesiredAccuracy.Low);

                if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
                {
                    locationBlock.Text = "City: " + result.Locations[0].Address.Town;
                }
```

**problem ended, the rest is just for the context**

```
                // calculate time
                int[] sun = SunDate.CalculateSunriseSunset(51.434406, 6.762329);
                var sunrise = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, sun[0] / 60, sun[0] - (sun[0] / 60) * 60, 0);
                var sunset = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, sun[1] / 60, sun[1] - (sun[1] / 60) * 60, 0);

                //fit UI
                lightStartBox.Text = sunrise.Hour.ToString();
                darkStartBox.Text = sunset.Hour.ToString();

                // apply settings
                lightStartBox.IsEnabled = false;
                darkStartBox.IsEnabled = false;
                break;

            case GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
                locationCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                locationBlock.Text = "The App needs permission to location";
                await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-location"));
                break;

            case GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:
                locationCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
                locationBlock.Text = "The App needs permission to location";
                await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-location"));
                break;
        }
        return;
    }
```

If I close the program, it should also end the await task. Better: It should end the operation after he got the info.

Comment: If all this is done in an event handler (or separate thread), perhaps use of a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-an-async-task-or-a-list-of-tasks) would work?

Answer (score 0):

> If I close the program, it should also end the await task. Better: It should end the operation after he got the info.

I have run your code, but I could not reproduce the issue, I could get `MapLocationFinderResult` with low delay. I found you used [`MapLocationDesiredAccuracy.Low`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.maplocationdesiredaccuracy) parameter. And it will leverage the maps disk cache to get accurate info up to the city level. maps disk cache may cause this issue. You could try to use `MapLocationDesiredAccuracy.High` parameter.

As you see, `FindLocationsAtAsync` is [`IAsyncOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncoperation_tresult_) method. So, you could cancel it manually or set timeout cancel token.

**For example**

```
private IAsyncOperation<string> GetAsyncOperation()
{
    return AsyncInfo.Run<string>(
       (token) => // CancellationToken token
           Task.Run<string>(
               () =>
               {
                   token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(3000);
                   token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();     
                   return "hello";
               },
               token));
}

private IAsyncOperation<string> operation;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        operation = GetAsyncOperation();
        var res = await operation;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("method end");
    }

}
private void Cancel_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    operation?.Cancel();
}
```

**Set Timeout**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var source = new CancellationTokenSource(4000);
  var res = await GetAsyncOperation().AsTask(source.Token);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer.

`var source = new CancellationTokenSource(400);
            MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(geopoint, MapLocationDesiredAccuracy.Low).AsTask(source.Token);`

Is that enough for cancellation of this task? Because this also doesn't work

Comment: try set 1500 millisecond delay.

Comment: Problem is that he makes the task but still the CancellationToken doesn't end the task and I can't close my program correctly. Which UWP SDK-Version you use?

Comment: Interesting thing is: When I remove the MapLocationDesiredAccuracy he doesn't get finished the job (takes forever without low on my machine btw). So he doesn't await this task anymore (ends it?) and then continues with the rest of the code. But still: When I close my program a background thing still runs. And this only when this line is used. When I remove the MapLocationFinderResult the program closes reliable. This is pretty despairingly.

Comment: My project's target version is 17763 and the min version is 17134.

Comment: Is the background thing  you said a run time broker?

Comment: I don't know? I just write that code above. And something still runs in Background after closing my application. In Task-Manager I still see AutoNightMode.exe. I don't see anything realting with a runtime broker.

Thanks for your help.

I only use this UWP APIs in my WPF Application.

Comment: Do you means the above project is a wpf project?

Comment: For using the above api,  we need add `Location` capability in uwp  project manifest.

Comment: Sorry bro. I added the information that this is a WPF Project in the title of the post as a Tag together with other information. But the StackOverlow team removed that. It is a WPF Project and I added the UWP references to my project. I followed this intodructions: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/. Everything is working without problems. Only when I await the MapLocationFinder the Application Shutdown doesn't work. But I still get the data from the method that I need. I only added the reference.

Comment: Do you think a UWP project manifest would solve my issues with the never ending await of MapLocationFinder?

Comment: Yep, But I don't know how to add this capability for wpf project, May be you need check desktop - bridge [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known [bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed4fbea6-84f9-4c46-967f-78918e47327c/bug-in-maplocationfinderfindlocationsatasync?forum=bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols)

To work-around it I ended up setting a static flag on my App class so that when the app was shutting down it would force kill the process.

```
// Before call to MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync()
App.RequiresProcessKill = true;
```

and then in my shutdown process (ie in the OnClosed method of your main window) I forced closed the app if neccessary:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
     if (App.RequiresProcessKill)
     {
         var self = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
         self.Kill();
     }
}
```

Comment: nice "workaround" for only killing the app if necessary. nice! :)